# Change key that launches dash in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, activities-overview

Currently the <kbd>cmd</kbd> button on my mac keyboard launches the dash. How can I change this to a combination - say <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, disable the "Cmd" button, which likely corresponds to the <kbd>Super</kbd> (also known as <kbd>Windows</kbd>) key on other systems. This can be achieved with the `gsettings` terminal command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key ''
```

Then set a key to launch the dash to your preference:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings toggle-overview ['<Super>s', '<Super>Space']
```

Here, your choice of key is added to the already existing default binding `<Super>s`.

Instead of using the command line, you can also change such config settings using `dconf-editor`.

To revert any change, i.e., reset to default settings, you can use `gsettings` with the `reset` option:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.mutter overlay-key
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.keybindings toggle-overview
```