Remove assignment of [super] key from showing "activities" in Ubuntu 22.04
I have recently upgraded from Ubuntu 23.10 to Ubuntu 24.04. Before I had keyboard assignment [super]+z to change my keyboard layout (named "switch to next input source") and it worked like charm.
I can still switch languages in external apps, like browser and lyx, but when I press [super]+z in gedit, native text editor, libreoffice or other default programs it shows "activities" - overview of all opened apps (thumbnails of all opened windows) when I start pressing [super] instead of changing languages.
How could I disable this default [super] key behaviour?
If it matters, I use wayland windowing system, gnome version 46, linux kernel 6.8.0-35 generic. My other keyboard shortcuts like [super]+[esc], [super]+[tab], [super]+1,2,3 work. The problem arises only with [super]+z to switch language.
UPDATE: I've ended up setting change of input source with [ctrl]+[shift] as in Windows. To do that, I executed
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Control>Shift_L']"


It is not clear what may be causing the keyboard combination Super+z to misbehave. The normal situation is that the activities overview is only shown after hitting and releasing Super. So pressing and holding Super, then pressing z should trigger the action assigned to that keyboard combination, without triggering the overview.
Perhaps first check your keyboard assignment. A workaround indeed will be to disable using Super alone to show the application overview.
As you ask in the title of your question, you can disable the assignment of hitting and releasing Super alone for showing the overview (see also here). The setting is not exposed in "Settings", but you can change it using following command:
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key ""

You can still setup a keyboard combination to show the overview, e.g. Super+Space in "Settings", "Keyboard settings", section "System": "Show the overview".

Just to complement your working solution I would recommend telling how to revert this change from here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1121056/change-key-that-launches-dash-in-ubuntu-18-04 (in ubuntu 22.04 it also works)

Thanks. I guess the problem with [super]+Z was that in other language Z was no longer Z but a letter in cyrillic language. So after pressing [super]+cyrillic it fell back to default [super] behaviour. Didn't find a way in Ubuntu 22.04 to solve this, so changed to [Ctrl]+[Shift] switching.
